# Why does this PHP think that "email" == "domain"?

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP:

```
$ec = $trimmed['emails'];//has a value of "email"
$dc = $trimmed['date'];//has a value of "timestamp"

$data = array("email","domain","timestamp");

$num = count($data);

for ($i=0; $i<$num; $i++){

    if ($data[$i] == $ec) {
        $ec = $i;
    } else if ($data[$i] == $dc) {
        $dc = $i;
    }    
}
```

When I run this PHP $ec ends up equaling the location of domain and not email. Also, it is clear that the first if thinks both "email" and "domain" are equivalent to "email" because when I echoed out the loop the first time it shows $ec as "email". Any ideas why?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but this code looks like a buggy way of writing [`array_search`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php). Maybe switching to that will solve your problem entirely. As for the answer itself, consider that *any* string is equal to the integer 0 when compared with `==`.

Comment: Your code is a bug, please post the point of this code and more data, I'm sure it can be written other way.

Comment: Debug your code and you'd know exactly why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because on the second iteration `$ec` (which is now `0`) is compared with `"domain"`, which evaluates to true, proven with a simple `var_dump( 0 == "domain");`, which outputs `true`.

As William Van Rensselaer suggests below, you can either use `===`, or check out the function [array_search](http://php.net/array_search), which will accomplish exactly what you're trying to do.

Example:

```
$ec = array_search( $data, $trimmed['emails']);
$dc = array_search( $data, $trimmed['date']);
```

Comment: I would also add that you should use === (not ==) to check equality in PHP.

Answer (score 3):

On the first iteration of the loop, when `$i == 0`, `$ec` is set to 0, correctly.

On the second iteration of the loop when `$i == 1` it tests `$data[1]` against the new value of `$ec`. So `"domain"` gets interpreted as a number (0), and `0 == 0` is `true`, so `$ec` is set to 1.